# SSAS Tabular Data Cube - Fact Table with partition of 160K row partition takes almost an hour to process...Why?

Tags: ssas, partition, ssas-tabular

I have an SSAS Tabular data model I developed with VS. In this cube there are many fact and dimension tables with lots of measures. HOWEVER, there is one fact table that in total has 158 million rows and to process all 158 million rows in this one fact table takes over an hour... To speed up that processing time I decided to create two partitions based on a date column. Partition 1 has historical data and when loaded has 157 million rows, Partition 2 (One month of data) has about 160,000 rows so VERY VERY small. I only want to process the Partition 2 daily. Unfortunately, when I process just Partition 2 the processing time is still almost an hour?? How can it be that simply refreshing a 160K partition takes 58 minutes... seems like it is still trying to process the full table….

I will say when I try to process a separate table that only has 200K rows in total I am able to process this in under 30 seconds. Shouldn't the partition 2 above also process in under a minute?? What would I be doing wrong here and why would this take so long to process a small partition.

In Summary:

Table A = 158,000,000 Rows = 1 Hour 13 Min to Process total table Partition 1 = 157,840,000 Rows = 1 hour to process FULL Partition 2 = 160,000 Rows = 58 minutes to process FULL

Table B = 200,000 Rows = 30 Seconds to process FULL Partition 1 = 200,000 Rows  = 30 Seconds to process!

Shouldn't Table A/Partition 2 take 30 seconds to process just like Table B?

I just want to process full the Partition 2 of Table A... Expected process time I expected to be was under 5 min... similar to Table B result time. Instead to process Partition 2 with 160K rows takes almost same time as entire table A (Partition 1 + 2).

Comment: Run the [Profiler][1] against both the underlying datasource server and the SSAS instance to see the acutal queries being executed and the time it takes in both. This is likely to give clues to where the most time is spent by the process.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

If you have calculated columns or DAX tables that refer to this table, they will have to process after the partition loads and could result in an extended load time. You might be able to test for this by creating a new table with a filter like the partition and see how long it takes to load.

I would also make sure the sort on the table is set to the date.